# Displaying a fading balloon type message box

Tags: vb.net

I need to have a balloon like message box that displays for a few seconds and then fades away (not disappears at once)

Please advise how to do this.

Thanks 
Furqan

Comment: Show what you have done so far....where are you having issues? Is this wpf or winforms?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dim buttonToolTip As New ToolTip()
with buttonToolTip
    .ToolTipTitle = "Button Tooltip"
    .UseFading = True
    .UseAnimation = True
    .IsBalloon = True
    .ShowAlways = True
    .AutoPopDelay = 5000
    .InitialDelay = 1000
    .ReshowDelay = 500
    .IsBalloon = True
    .SetToolTip(Button1, "Click me to execute.")
End With
```

**EDITED**:
If you need a fading MessageBox, you can do this:

- create a form that accepts a status and a text in constructor
- swtich on status drawing correct icon and place text on form
- create a timer and on `Tick` event check if it's time to close
- if it's time to close call `FadeForm` method

Example:

```
public enum Status
{
    None,
    Error,
    Question,
    Warning,
    Info
}

public class FadingForm: Form
{
    dt: TDateTime;

    public FadingForm(Status status, string msg)
    {
        this.lbl.Text = msg; // I imagine you have a Label named lbl
        switch (status)
        {
            case Warning: 
                img.Image = warning; // I imagine you have a PictureBox named img
                break;
            case ...
        }
        dt = DateTime.Now;
        tmr.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Tmr_Tick() 
    {
        if (DateTime.Now - dt) > limit
        {
            FadeForm(10); //Just an example
            Close();
        }
    }

    public void FadeForm(byte NumberOfSteps)  
    {  
        float StepVal = (float)(100f / NumberOfSteps);  
        float fOpacity = 100f;  
        for (byte b = 0; b < NumberOfSteps; b++)  
        {  
            this.Opacity = fOpacity / 100;  
            this.Refresh();  
            fOpacity -= StepVal;  
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the email.  I donot mean to use a tooptip.  I need a message box..............

Answer (score 1):

I think this behavior depends on users windows settings, if you want to achieve this you can code a balloon message your self and decrease its opacity before closing it completely.